# Photoshop smart object: get rotation angle via Applescript?

Tags: applescript, photoshop

I have tried and failed to find an Applescript code that returns a smart object's current rotation angle in Photoshop. Anyone have an idea of where that property is listed? I'm beginning to think this feature isn't currently supported by Applescript.

Answer (score 0):

In Photoshop, objects like a selection has no angle value, because it means nothing: if your selection is made by multiple segments making a complexe shape, there is no mathematical way you can define angle for that shape !

However, you can work with boundary rectangle (which includes that shape). You can rotate this complete boundary (i.e. the selection) and then you will get a new boundary (new rectangle where new rotated shape fits in).

A boundary rectangle is made of a list of for values :

- top left corner horizontal position (X1)
- top left corner vertical position (Y1)
- bottom right corner horizontal position (X2)
- bottom right corner vertical position (Y2)

Positions are real numbers, starting with border of canvas (not border of layer ! so you may have negative values). The units depends of the unit of measure of the document.

Once that's clear (I hope !) if you use mathematical calculation between initial boundary and new boundary, you can calculate the rotation angle:
(Pythagore triangle)
If you assume that initial rectangle borders were vertical and horizontal :
cosinus (Teta) = (X2-X1) / (X'2 - X'1)
Teta = angle you are looking for
X1, X2 are the positions of the boundary corners before rotation and X'1, X'2 are position of same corners after rotation.

Please note that this method is OK for selection (any shape), or layers. 
It should also be OK for the full canvas, but I never test it for canvas.

Comment: That would work IF I had the boundary values for the UN-rotated smart object. If a smart object is rotated, Applescript only returns the current boundary coordinates -- not the un-rotated ones.

Comment: A smart object is not a normal selection. It remembers its rotation values and displays them in the info panel in degrees of rotation. Clearly, the rotation value is stored somewhere. The other problem is, while you can determine the angle of rotation, you will not be able to tell whether it was positive or negative. +5 degrees and -5 degrees will create the same boundary.